# A task failed to un-serialize

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to evaluate an ANN. I get the accuracies if I use `n_jobs = 1`, however, when I use `n_jobs = - 1` I get the following error.
    `BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that the arguments of the function are all picklable.`

I have tried using other numbers but it only works if I use `n_jobs = 1`

This is the code I am running:
    `accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)`

This is the error I am getting:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<ipython-input-12-cc51c2d2980a>", line 1, in <module>
 accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = classifier, X = X_train, 
 y = y_train, cv = 10, n_jobs = -1)

 File "C:\Users\javie\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 402, in 
 cross_val_score
 error_score=error_score)

 File "C:\Users\javie\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py", line 240, in 
 cross_validate
 for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))

 File "C:\Users\javie\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 930, in __call__
 self.retrieve()

 File "C:\Users\javie\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve
 self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))

 File "C:\Users\javie\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in 
 wrap_future_result
 return future.result(timeout=timeout)

 File "C:\Users\javie\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 
 432, in result
 return self.__get_result()

 File "C:\Users\javie\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 
 384, in __get_result
 raise self._exception

 BrokenProcessPool: A task has failed to un-serialize. Please ensure that 
 the arguments of the function are all picklable.`
```

Spyder should have analyzed each batch in parallel, but even when I use `n_jobs = 1` it only analyzes 10 epochs.

Answer (score 13):

This always happens when using multiprocessing in an iPython console in Spyder. A workaround is to run the script from the command line instead.

Comment: I was having the same problem and moving from Spyder to command line fixed this error (although I now have others to deal with!).

Comment: Hmm I am running in ipython, I had this issue... But I got that one only if i import joblib in ipython. If i dont and only do it in the module where my functions are difined it works fine....

Comment: I am using the command line and it still shows me the same error when I am using the joblib library.

Answer (score 9):

Just posting this for others, in case it's helpful. I Ran into the same issue today running a GridSearchCV on a Dask array / cluster. Sklearn v.0.24

Solved it by using the joblib context manager as described here: https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html#thread-based-parallelism-vs-process-based-parallelism

Comment: Life saver ! (Y)

Comment: how did you use it? i wish you would have provided some code.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error as well, but only on Windows. I am using joblib to run a function (call it `func_x`) in parallel. That function is imported from a module, let's call it `module_a`.

`module_a` also uses a function (call it `func_y`) from another module, `module_b`, which it imports using the syntax `import module_b`.

I found that I can avoid the BrokenProcessPool error if I edit `module_a` and change the import line to `from module_b import func_y`.

I also had to remove the `if __name__ == '__main__:'` from the main script which was importing `module_a`.

I think this subtle difference in how modules are imported to the namespace determines whether that module can then be pickled by joblib for parallel processing in Windows.

I hope this helps!

--

A minimal reproducible example is below:

**Original main.py**

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import module_a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Parallel(n_jobs=4, verbose=3)(delayed(module_a.func_x)(i) for i in range(50))
```

**Original module_a.py** (fails on Windows with BrokenProcessPool error; kernel restart required)

```py
import module_b

def func_x(i):
    j = i ** 3
    k = module_b.func_y(j)
    return k
```

**Edited main.py**

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import module_a

Parallel(n_jobs=4, verbose=3)(delayed(module_a.func_x)(i) for i in range(50))
```

**Edited module_a.py** (succeeds on Windows)

```py
from module_b import func_y # changed

def func_x(i):
    j = i ** 3
    k = func_y(j) # changed
    return k
```

**module_b.py**

```py
def func_y(m):
    k = j ** 3
    return k
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spyder IDE simply switch to external terminal in settings (run>execute in an external system terminal).

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar error when I was using RandomizedSearchCV with all possible cores and threads. Realized that I am getting this error only when the number of combinations I was sampling from the parameter space is a less number like 5. When I selected a higher *n_iter* value, the issue was fixed. I believe it has something to with the fact that the number *fits* happening should be at least greater than the number cores and parallel compute units on your system
Hope this might help someone later.